# Can we monitor a host in rollbar?

Tags: rollbar

I have been using Rollbar and it helps us diagnose production problems. I would like to have an alarm (email or slack) that notifies me if a host is not logging any thing in 24 hours. That tells me the host might be down. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there no such (or equivalent) notification implemented, however, this was just reported to the dashboard development team as a new feature request and was placed on their development backlog. It most likely will get implemented sometime by the end of the year 2020.

Meantime, depending on what kind of Rollbar SDK is used by your application, something similar could be implemented as a custom SDK extension feature.

For example, Rollbar.NET SDK implements the internal SDK events mechanism that could be used to subscribe to the successful payload transmission events and it does not get fired at least once within a 24-hour window - send an email. Or something like that.

We can probably implement somewhat similar notification events within Rollbar-iOS SDK as well. It should not take more than a week or two to get it out.